# Evaluate the Contour Integral around curve

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate the contour integral: 
   $$ I = \int_{C_0} \frac{dz}{z^2+z} $$
where the curve $C_0$ in the complex plane is given by: 
   $$ C_0 = \{z : |z| = 1 \text{ and } z \neq -1\}$$
and the integral is taken in the counterclockwise direction on the curve.

I thought about using residue theorem to evaluate this, but I wasn't sure if the fact that the region we are integrating around isn't closed (since we are not including -1) will mean that I can't use residue theorem.

Comment: The main issue here is that we have a singularity lying on $C_0$ (if we include $z=-1$). I doubt this is well-defined as the residue at this pole is non-zero. Anyway what you can do is to change variables $z = e^{i t}$ to get an integral over $(-\pi,\pi)$. If this is well defined then you can evaluate this on $[-\pi-\epsilon_1,\pi+\epsilon_2]$ and then take $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \to 0$.

Comment: The problem is that you are integrating "right up to" one of the poles.  Including a point or not in an integral should not change the value.  Nevertheless, if you were to take a semicircle or some other curve to go around $z=-1$, and let its radius go to zero, would the union of the semicircle with the "almost circle" surround this pole or not?  Perhaps we can define the principal value of this integral to be $2\pi i \cdot \textrm{ residue at } z=0 - \textrm{ half the residue}$ at $z=-1.$

Comment: There is some ambiguity about how to evaluate this (which is why I said its not well defined). If you take the symmetric limit in my comment above; integrate over $[-\pi-\epsilon,\pi+\epsilon]$ and then take $\epsilon \to 0$ then you will get a finite answer. In the residue setting this basically amounts to including $1/2$ of the residue at $z=-1$. Depending on how you define it you can either include none of this, all of this or some of this contribution.